# json_decode returns null with PHP, NFL API

Tags: php, null, json

For some reason json_decode is returning NULL with valid JSON.

The json is located here: http://www.nfl.com/liveupdate/scorestrip/scorestrip.json

I am getting the file contents of the page (file_get_contents) and then running json_decode on it.

Also tried stripslashes b/c of magic quotes.

Thanks in advance,
Phil

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://www.nfl.com/liveupdate/scorestrip/scorestrip.json');

var_dump(json_decode($json));
```

Comment: Check the json first: `var_dump($json);` - does it still look valid?

Comment: `json_decode` returns NULL if the json is broken. Better look twice, put it into some json syntax checker, there should be one online. **Edit:** I think [Phil](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072885/json-decode-returns-null-with-php-nfl-api/7072934#7072934) is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The empty array elements are invalid JSON, ie the multiple commas with no values between

```
["Thu","7:30","Final",,"BAL","6","PHI","13",,,"55424",,"PRE1","2011"]
                      ^ Here                ^ Here    ^Here
```

You could try inserting empty strings between multiple commas (thanks [hakre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367456/hakre)), ie

```
$json = preg_replace('/,(?=,)/m', ',""', $json);
// I'm dubious about this working, don't have PHP to test but it works in JS
```

I don't know if this messes up your ability to continue using the data though

Comment: I suspect those commas as well. Replacing with one should not work as this will mess up the numerical indexes of the values. How about making the elements empty strings?

Answer (score 1):

I came the same conclusion as Phil, but it took me about 5 minutes longer.  : )

However, I noticed a problem in his output... it is dropping a field.

I don't like doing this kind of pattern detection in RegEx, only because I think it is harder to maintain.  In this case, I just run it through a while loop.

```
while (strpos($json,',,'))
{
    $json = str_replace(',,',',"",', $json);
}
```

I'm sure Phil can come up with a proper RegEx, but this solution will maintain the right # of entries & their ordinal positions.

Comment: Apparently, I'm just slow today.  His updated answer alleviates the original problem.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking in 2014. The new feed data link should be:

http://www.nfl.com/liveupdate/scores/scores.json